# How to compute fundamental groups of slice disk complements?

Tags: gn.general-topology, knot-theory, fundamental-group

To compute the fundamental group of the complement $S^3 \setminus K$ of a knot, one usually uses the Wirtinger algorithm. Is there a similarly well-established procedure for computing the fundamental group of complements of slice disks in the $4$-ball?

---

As a partial solution and as an example of what kind of solution would satisfy me, I (and probably also other people) managed to find a cool way of computing ribbon disk complements. Here, a *ribbon disk* is a smooth disk $R \subset B^4$ in the $4$-ball such that $\partial R \subset S^3$ and the height-function $\Vert \cdot \Vert \rightarrow \mathbb [0, 1]$ restricted to the interior of $R$ has no local maxima.

The Wirtinger-like procedure I (and probably also other people) came up with that meets my requirement goes as follows. By a general position argument, after projecting to $S^3$ we can think about $R$ as represented by a "ribbon diagram" $D \subset S^3$, where $D$ is an immersed disk that only has so-called "ribbon singularities": 
The left-hand singularity in the following picture is a ribbon singularity, but the right-hand singularity is not.
[image: Ribbon singularity example and counterexample]
These sorts of diagrams will now play the same role as planar knot diagrams play in the usual Wirtinger procedure. Let $S$ be the union of the singular points of $D$. Then an *arc* of $D$ is a connected component of $D \setminus S$, and a *crossing* is a connected component of $S$. Orienting the boundary in an arbitrary way, we get a presentation of $\pi_1(B^4 \setminus R)$ by taking the set of arcs of $D$ as generators (interpreted as meridians of $R$ in a very similar way as in the usual setting $K \subset S^3$), and adding the relation $bc=ca$ at every crossing that looks as follows:

[image]

The proof that this indeed gives rise to a presentation of $\pi_1(B^4 \setminus R)$ is a van Kampen argument not unlike the one usually used to prove correctness of the Wirtinger algorithm.

Comment: Page 213 of Gompf-Stipsicz's book explains how to get a Kirby diagram for a ribbon disc complement. You can then read off the fundamental group from there.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this book, it totally slipped my mind, shame on me. But just to be clear, this is not meant to answer my question, right? Or can we do something similar for slice disks?